# iOS 13 Apple-App-Site-Association file format changes

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am having inconsistent results when it comes to supporting Universal Links in my app. I had things working with the following format (I changed my APP ID here even though it's publicly available at the domain):

```
{
   "webcredentials": {
       "apps": ["APPID.com.kasey.TipMe"]
   },
   "applinks": {
       "apps": [],
       "details": [{
           "appID": "APPID.com.kasey.TipMe",
           "paths": [
               "/pay"
           ]
       }]
   }
}
```

I have the associated domain in my entitlements file properly with the fully qualified domain: applinks:www.tppy.app

Then I stumbled upon [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains_in_your_app) that seems to have changed the format and location of the apple-app-site-association file. I moved the file to /.well-known/apple-app-site-association and am serving the JSON. Does anyone know if the new format is required for iOS 13+ applications? Or 
why am I seeing inconsistent results? The universal links seem to work for a period of time then stop working -- both when I distribute the application via TestFlight as well connect it directly to my device.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 13 and later new format has been introduce you can check here
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains_in_your_app

So refer this link and you can prepare your JSON file and validate it with
https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/